# Error message: Error copying design elements

Tags: xpages

I get this error message in Designer for my xPages application:

> "The project was not built due to "Error copying design elements". Fix
>   the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it
>   may be inconsistent."

Using the latest Ext.Lib and 8.5.3

No errors is visible in the database design. I've checked both in native Designer windows and in Package Explorer…

Copying the database or making a new replica will not fix it.

Please advice!

/Mike

Comment: I solved it by deleting all design elements and copying them back in from a backup. It boiled down to Script Libraries where the problem was located. These had to be copied one by one.

Comment: Well, the happiness was short. The error returned suddenly without doing anything.
I think I'll try to create a new database and then copying them over…

Answer (score 2):

Try also the Project ==> Clean and Project ==> Build All actions. Usually these does the work. Might take some time depending on the size of your application.

Also the designer restart helps (usually)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried closing and reopening Designer?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the NSF/NTF from your Domino Designer application pane and then exit Domino Designer and your Notes client

Once Designer has quit go to the program files\notes\data\workspace folder in Windows Explorer and see if there is a folder for the server on which you opened the database in designer. In that folder there may be a subfolder with the name of the NSF/NTF. if there is then delete it and then go back up one folder and find the 'local' folder and see if it exists there also and if so delete it.

Now restart Domino Designer and add the database back in to Domino Designer and it should be able to create the required files.

My guess is that there are some leftover files that it is having difficulty overwriting. Maybe a permissions change in Windows...

Comment: Sorry but this did not fix the problem.